# jQuery Syntax Error in on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble with my code. Specifically it is my jQuery click function. This may seem trivial, but I could not get it to respond whenever I tried to click a link. I tried to debug it, I updated to the latest jQuery. Then I put it into a Jsfiddle bin with the latest jQuery .... no dice. I honestly don't have a clue what I did wrong. I get a highlighted error on my ("nav a") jQuery selector but I have double checked with the internet and that is the proper syntax and it still won't run. 
Below is my code. I cannot paste full HTML in here as it would become links as well.

```
$(document.ready(function(){
  $("nav a").on("click",function(){
       alert("What's WRONGG!");
   });

});
```

I am using jQuery 2.1.4 on local and 2.1.3 on jsfiddle if that makes a difference. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uuhh1s53/8/).

Comment: One problem is a missing end paren on `$(document`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are missing a parenthesis on your $(document)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("nav a").on("click",function(){
       alert("What's WRONGG!");
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `)` bracket near  `$(document`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("nav a").on("click",function(){
       alert("What's WRONGG!");
   });

});
```